# Internet Explorer Developer Tool with Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

When I worked on ASP.NET web forms, I found IE developer tool extremely useful to debug my Javascript and CSS issues.

I cannot seem to make that tool work with my Silverlight application. I was trying to use  "Select Element by Click" feature and it was not selecting any elements on my silverlight application.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements on your Silverlight application are not HTML elements, they are embedded in your Silverlight application, so the developer tool cannot see them.

Comment: Jeff,
Is there any other tool which can work as the IE developer tool for a silverlight application ?

Comment: @SVI: Not that I was aware of, but apparently there is SilverlightSpy (see Mike's answer)

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff Yates pointed out Silverligh is object, so you cannot inspect something. I can suggest to try [SilverlightSpy](http://silverlightspy.com/).